# Apply function to two columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to apply a function that calculates the R2 score to two columns of a pandas data frame. It works if first I group by some other column but when applied to the whole dataframe it fails.

This is the code that works:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':['A','A','B','B'], 'num1':[.1,.2,.3,.4], 
'num2': [.1,.2,.3,.4]})

df.groupby('cat').apply(lambda x: r2_score(x['num1'],x['num2']))
```

With this output:

```
cat
A    1.0
B    1.0
dtype: float64
```

But this doesn't work:

```
df.apply(lambda x: r2_score(x['num1'],x['num2']))
```

With a key error:
    KeyError: ('num1', 'occurred at index cat')

Could anyone explain why this is the case clarifying the inner workings of the apply function and provide a solution for the latter apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need pass columns to function:

```
a = r2_score(df['num1'],df['num2'])
print (a)
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, you should specify that "apply" run per row, so axis=1:

```
df.apply(lambda x: r2_score(x['num1'],x['num2']), axis=1)
```

Your code tries to run it vertically, on columns, and doesn't find the relevant keys.

But note that this is not equivalent to what you did with grouping. So it's up to you what exactly you're trying to do.

see documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: I don't have access to this module. Indeed it depends on the function you're trying to run and what arguments it accepts. In general, when trying to apply row by row you need to use axis=1. If this function accepts whole columns then @Jerzrael's answer is favourable.